# Updating the Angular app from version 4.x.x to 6.0

Tags: angular, angular6

I have a very big project with a lot of components. Actually it is an open source project to which I am contributing.It was built on Angular 4. Currently it is running on Angular 4. I am trying to update it by following this site https://update.angular.io/ and manually searching for use of each dependency and rewriting code for it according to Angular 6 is very hectic.I am getting a lot of errors solving which gives rise to another errors.So my question is,Is it necessary to update my app to latest Angular 6? If yes then are not their some easy ways to do that.
Further I read this `We do not recommend moving across multiple major versions.` under warning on https://update.angular.io/ . Is updating my app required.

Comment: It's not strictly necessary to update; only if you want to be able to use new features or if you really have the time / ability to upgrade.

Comment: You have 2 options: upgrade first to version 5, make a stable version., Than upgrade from 5 to 6. This is whar "We do not recommend moving across multiple major versions" means. Or you stand in version 4, no problems. But than you won't be able to upgrade other dependencies, maybe add new modules, etc...

Answer (score 0):

I think you should migrate since 4 version is deprecated for reasons below:

**Reasons to migrate to Angular 7**

- Lack of documentation and support on eventual bugs on the deprecated versions
- The ability to use the latest features https://blog.angular.io/tagged/release-notes
- If we have the latest version it’ll be easier to upgrade from 7 to the latest versions just by running a command
- Performance Optimizations
- Bug fixes
- Bugs in deprecated version won’t be fixed included security issues

**What is the warning of moving across major versions about**

From the updating guide https://angular.io/guide/updating it implies that the tool “Angular Update Guide.” may take some manual changes and for major versions they recommend take into the account the needed changes below but you may need to create a new project from scratch and start moving your components to this new one applying the AUG recommendations.

Looking at the Deprecation Policies it seems like Long-term support for v4.x.x is over:

https://angular.io/guide/releases#support-policy-and-schedule

[image]